# How qualification conversion is done?

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

I have an example:

```
int i = 1;
const int *b = &i;
```

In this case, what i don't understand is,
When the address of `i` gets converted to pointer to const int. Doesn't the `i` gets converted to a const integer in qualification conversion? what exactly happens under the hood when qualification conversion is applied?

Answer (score 6):

Nothing happens under the hood. `const` is strictly compile time entity. the compiler only uses the knowledge of `const` to decide whether a statement is an error and not for generating code. thus the following:

```
int i = 1;
const int *b = &i;
```

is equivalent to

```
int i = 1;
int *b = &i;
```

in term of generated code. however if you do the following:

```
int i = 1;
const int *b = &i;
*b = 1;
```

the compiler will notice `b` has `const` (while it knows nothing of `i`) and will error out.   However, any statement that isn't considered an error with added const will generate the same code with or without const.

Comment: +1 helpful. Which reference or book does this answer come from?

Comment: @user1086635: I don't have a reference for this, but I'm sure you can find it somewhere in the standard.

Answer (score 1):

> address of i gets converted to pointer to const int

**No**. `&i` is still an address of `int` (not `const int`). Under the hood `int*` is implicitly converted to `const int*`. Thus `*b` is not modifiable, however `i` is still modifiable.

Also, think in different way: if your assumption is true then following will give compiler error, but it doesn't:

```
int i = 1;
const int *b = &i;
int *c = &i; // perfectly valid !
```